# Create multidimensional object from after some calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've some fieldset with input fields like:

```
<fieldset>
PRICE: <input type="text" class="price" value="100"><br>
TAX %: <input type="text" class="tax" value="22"><br>
TOTAL: <input type="text" class="total" value="122"><br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
PRICE: <input type="text" class="price" value="200"><br>
TAX %: <input type="text" class="tax" value="22"><br>
TOTAL: <input type="text" class="total" value="244"><br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
PRICE: <input type="text" class="price" value="100"><br>
TAX %: <input type="text" class="tax" value="10"><br>
TOTAL: <input type="text" class="total" value="110"><br>
</fieldset>
```

I've to create an object grouped by TAX value to pass to a script that creates a dynamic table where columns are TAXes, and row the data with sum of each fieldset where TAX are the same. With the example above:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>TAXes</th>
  <th>22</th>
  <th>10</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>PRICE</td>
   <td>300</td>
   <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>TOTAL</td>
   <td>366</td>
   <td>110</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For my purpose I need to create an object like:

```
{
   {"columnTitle": 22,
   "columnVisibility": true,
   "data": {
        "price": 300,
        "total": 366
   }},
  {
   "columnTitle": 10,
   "columnVisibility": true,
   "data": {
        "price": 100,
        "total": 110
  }}
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get started, apart from

```
   var array_iva = [];

   $("fieldset").each(function(){

    var tax = $(this).find(".tax").val();

    if ( tax != "" ) {
        var already_present = array_iva.some(function(value) {
            return value == tax;
        });
        if ( !already_present) {
            array_iva.push(tax);
        }
    }

});
```

But this script only creates an object with tax values like [ 22, 10]

Comment: What part specifically do you not understand? It sort of seems like you are asking us to write your code for you. You're going to have to give a bit more effort than that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to update an already pushed value inside the JSON. I'll post my partial code now

Comment: This looks like a nested data structure, not JSON. JSON is a string format.

Comment: I've update my code I used to search different taxes...but i don't know how to proceed with my purpose :(

Comment: Still not entirely clear how to group these. Use tax=22 duplicate as example, price and totals will differ but table shown doesn't indicate how you want them displayed

Comment: Your first line of code `var array_iva = [];` and you expect to get an Object? :D

Comment: @connexo No, that was my edit (ok, it said "a JSON" before, which is even more wrong). But arrays are objects.

Comment: SOrry for my english. for example where tax = 22, i've to sum the .price class, so 100 + 200 = 300. and the .total sum is 122+ 244 = 366. tax = 10 occurs only one time so i've only price = 100 and total = 110. All those datas i've to group like the example above to manage creation of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jsfiddle I think is ok, but probably someone else can create a better and more light code?

```
var array_iva = [];

   $("fieldset").each(function(){

    var price = $(this).find(".price").val();
    var tax = $(this).find(".tax").val();
    var total = $(this).find(".total").val();

    if ( tax != "" ) {

         var index_found = "";

       for (var i = 0; i < array_iva.length; i++) {
            if(array_iva[i]['columnTitle'] == tax) {
            index_found = i;
          }
         }

        if ( index_found === "" ) {

            var data = { "price": price, "total": total };
            var iva = { "columnTitle": tax, "columnVisibility": true, "data": data };

            array_iva.push(iva);
        } else {
            array_iva[index_found]['data']['price'] = parseFloat(array_iva[index_found]['data']['price']) + parseFloat(price);
          array_iva[index_found]['data']['total'] = parseFloat(array_iva[index_found]['data']['total']) + parseFloat(total);
        }
    }

        });

    console.log(array_iva);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/md3dcn24/19/

Comment: It seem to be ok! :)